# IE EDGE/ 11: user is not able to upload audio/video file , it display message "the file format is not supported"

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I'm working with an application where in i require to upload audio/image/video/pdf file , sometimes they get uploaded and sometimes it display message "file format is not supported". This issue is specific to IE EDGE and IE11 only, it works good in rest of the browsers.